# Restrict api calls with service worker, Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http, service-worker

I would like to find a way, through a service worker, to intercept the API calls to a specific endpoint and identify if more than 10 calls are being made in one second, if so, throw an error or stop the application

any ideas?

Comment: If you're making the calls using Angular `HttpClient` module, then you have control over frequency of the calls. Angular doesn't automatically fire multiple requests.

Comment: What happens is the requests are to an error API and the request is fired every time an error happens. It happened that an error in angular routes entered an infinite bluce and saturated the call server.

Comment: If you have an error prone please include it in the question. Without it everyone is left to guesswork.

Comment: The bug is fixed, I just try to find an improvement in error handling to avoid future side effects. There is absolutely nothing to guess, the question in this post is very specific.